# How to bind JTS Geometry via JDBI

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis, jdbi

I am trying to use JDBI with PostgreSQL geometric type and get the following error:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException with message:   
No argument factory registered for type [com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry]
```

The Geometry is part of a bean I am binding with `.bindBean()`.

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354903/jdbi-postgis-jts-wrapper) but the answers are not so helpful.

What is the best approach for binding such type?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Jts geometry to geoJson and then bind the geoJson as string in Jdbi.

```
public class GeometryUtils {
    private static final GeometryJSON geometryJSON = new GeometryJSON(10);
    
    private static String writeToGeoJson(Geometry geometry) throws IOException {
        final var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        geometryJSON.write(geometry, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

and then let's say your sql query looks like this

```
INSERT INTO XYZ(shape) VALUES (st_geomfromgeojson(:shape::jsonb))
```

and  bind  `shape` as `GeometryUtils.writeToGeoJson(geom)`